# Can not change TextView text while app is creating

Tags: android

I am new in android development, i have created a very simple app that has a single `TextView` in `fragment_main.xml`, i just want the `textview's` text changes while app is creating (starting), but i recieve error **"Unfortunately, demo3 has stopped"**. What is wrong with my code? Please tell me what is exactly wrong....

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.demo3.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and **java code**:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textview.setText("hello world!");
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Look at the logcat, please copy the stacktrace into your answer by clicking on the edit button.

Comment: i do not think there is any need for logcat, i am wrong in the fundamentals , is it ok to accessing to textview from Oncreate(), the textview is in fragment_main.xml??

Comment: @user3618000 no you should do it in Fragment. Fragment is attached to the Activity

Comment: The logcat often helps best with that kind of stuff, especially if your program crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TextView` belongs to the `Fragment Layout`. So initialize the `TextView` in Fragment's `onCreateView`.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);  
         TextView textview = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         textview.setText("hello world!");
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: thank you!, it worked, but can you explain me exactly what was the problem? why i can not access to textview from Oncreate()?

Comment: @user3618000 you inflate the layout in framgent you can find view by id in the current view hierarchy. You use the inflated layout to initialize views. So you need to change as above